# Is file copying limited by free space on C drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, copy, robocopy

I have some Windows Server 2003 and 2008 boxes that have files I need to copy that are in the range of 20 GB to 80 GB ranges.  The 20 GB files transfer without a problem from one server to another using UNC path.  The 80 GB files do not.  I get a message telling me that is out of space.  I am transferring from the D drive on one server to the D drive on the other which has a few hundred GB left.  However, the C drive on both servers only has 60 GB left.  Is this the limiting factor?  If so, why?  This happens with drag and drop, copy and paste, and robocopy.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message that robocopy gives you?  Do you have any quotas set?  I assume the both the source and destination filesystems are NTFS?

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with buffered file copies.  Try getting your hands on eseutil.exe and ese.dell from an exchange server, then use it with the /j switch to perform an unbuffered copy.

Comment: @phoebus - xcopy (builtin) can do that (same /j switch) but it is very slow.  OP - have you tried using something like FTP instead?

Comment: @TheCleaner I was suggesting that more as a test than as a solution, to see if things change when unbuffered.

Comment: @phoebus - I know, I'm stating that there's no need to get eseutil when xcopy can perform an unbuffered copy and it is already available.

Comment: I appreciate all the posts.  Strangely when attempting from both servers today using the original robocopy I received no errors.  The 80 GB file copied fine, so my hypothesis that it is related to the free space on C is wrong.  I do not have any quotas set.  If it happens again I will grab the errors and try xcopy with /j switch.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not copy file into network share bigger than available space in drive C: if offline files are enabled in Sync Center. Click Start - Type "Sync Center", and check if your share is marked as offline.**

This is not limited to servers, this can happen on any Windows version including Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Offline files can be easy enabled by accident (shortcut Alt + F, A -- used by "File save as"), by navigating with Windows Explorer to any shared file, and clicking "Always available offline" from context menu or file menu.

I just lost 1h searching for solution to this problem.