# Can't copy files to network share due to full local disk

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

So I am trying to copy files from my local D drive to a network share. However these are around the 150GB.

When I try to copy Windows says the destination is full and requires additional storage. When I delete a few files on my C disk, and then try again it says the same but then it requires a little bit less storage. So the problem is that the C disk has not enough free space to copy files from D:\ to \192.168.x.x\123

I am on Windows 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: There is a similar question asked here http://serverfault.com/questions/554857/is-file-copying-limited-by-free-space-on-c-drive

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use xcopy with the /j switch.
This switch does the following: "Copies files without buffering. Recommended for very large files."

```
    xcopy "d:\file" "\\192.168.x.x\123\file2" /j
```